# phonegap клавиатура закрывает поле ввода

Tags: javascript, phonegap

делаю на framework7 и появилась проблема, если по полю тапаю, которое низко, то появляющаяся клавиатура перекрывает поле и не видно что вводишь. как можно сделать так чтобы всегда поле ввода было выше клавиатуры? 
как сдвинуть блок вверх. точнее как сдвинуть чтобы поле оказалось над клавиатурой

Answer (score 1):

Вот плагин, который это делает:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-native-keyboard

Comment: а как нажатие на кнопку меню отловить? может тоже есть плагин?   document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false); - не работает